# Is "Let's start"grammatical correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Okay, What I have learned so far that if we add "To be verb" ( are, is, am) before verb words, the verbs will change to adjective. For instance,
* I am  interested, instead of I am interest 
* He is disappointed,  instead of He is disappoint.

My question is why many people say/spell "Let's start" instead of "Let's started"?

Comment: "let's" here means "let us" and not "let is". *Let us start planning for ...*, *Let us go eat now* ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't "add to be verbs before verbs".

You can form sentences that are [Subject] [be] [adjective].  And you can form sentences in the passive voice [Subject] [be] [past participle]  ([by phrase]).

However this is Irrelevant to the question. The word "Let's" is a contraction of "Let us"  The word "let" is a verb (in the imperative form) and it is followed by a verb in the bare infintive.

> Let us start.

It is similar in structure to

> Make us start.

or

> Ask us to start.

(except that "Ask" uses the to-infinitive and not the bare infinitive.

It is also valid to say

> Let me speak.  or Let him play

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "Let's Start" is correct. In fact, let's start with an example:

> Let's have lunch.

As a contraction of "Let us", it is an idiomatic invitation to do something together. "Let's have lunch" is a proposal or invitation to have lunch together (or break for lunch at the same time). "Us" refers to the speaker and anybody else they are addressing.

"Start" in your context means the same as "*begin*", so your phrase essentially means "*let's begin*". It might be said by a public speaker as a way of introducing the opening of a discussion, as I did at the beginning of this answer by using it to introduce the example.

---

As an aside, "start" can sometimes idiomatically mean "begin to cause trouble" by grumbling or criticising. "[Don't Let's Start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJQnZZ-Wmao)" is the title of a song, and the lyric essentially means "do not let us argue", or "let's not argue".